# What is this mood and tense of "I have to agree?"

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, infinitives, contractions

A non-native English speaker posted a comment: "I've to agree." At first, I thought it was a typo, but then realised the expansion "I have to agree" is (seems?) correct. So why is "I've to agree" incorrect? If it was "futurish" (sorry, i don't know the name, so I'm making one up) and used would or will (i would have to agree/ I will have to agree) it would be correct, if uncommon, to have a double contraction: I'd've / i'll've (although in that case, the verb becomes past tense: agreed).

Is this one of those things where the contraction is actually correct, but seems wrong? I have literally googled this for almost an hour and can't find this verb form (a present indicative with an infinitive verb?) in any of the grammar pages, but I hear this construction all the time (but without the contraction).

Comment: In American English, we only contract *have* when it's used as an auxiliary.  "I have never seen it" contracts to "I've never seen it"; but "I have a dog" **does not** contract to "I've a dog." Likewise, "I have to agree" does not contract to "I've to agree." I believe that in other dialects "I've a dog" is acceptable.  I don't know if "I've to agree" is acceptable anywhere.

Comment: "Have" is an auxiliary here, so syntactically it's best seen as present tense. Though not a modal verb, it does express obligation or necessity. The contracted form is heard, though perhaps not as often as the non-contracted form. It's quite common with "get", as "I've got to go to the dentist".

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I would say 'I have to agree" to mean "I feel impelled to agree" (with the accent on "have"), and if I heard someone say "I've to agree" would notice the dated usage and also assume they meant "I have been instructed to agree".